# Is Feign threadsafe...?

Tags: netflix-feign, feign

Is instance of Feign thread safe...? I couldn't find any documentation that supports this. Do anyone out there think otherwise?

Here is the standard example posted on github repo for Feign...

```
interface GitHub {
  @RequestLine("GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/contributors")
  List<Contributor> contributors(@Param("owner") String owner, @Param("repo") String repo);
}

static class Contributor {
  String login;
  int contributions;
}

public static void main(String... args) {
  GitHub github = Feign.builder()
                       .decoder(new GsonDecoder())
                       .target(GitHub.class, "https://api.github.com");

  // Fetch and print a list of the contributors to this library.
  List<Contributor> contributors = github.contributors("netflix", "feign");
  for (Contributor contributor : contributors) {
    System.out.println(contributor.login + " (" + contributor.contributions + ")");
  }
}
```

Should I change this to following... Is it thread safe...?

```
interface GitHub {
  @RequestLine("GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/contributors")
  List<Contributor> contributors(@Param("owner") String owner, @Param("repo") String repo);
}

static class Contributor {
  String login;
  int contributions;
}

@Component
public class GithubService {

  GitHub github = null;

  @PostConstruct
  public void postConstruct() {
    github = Feign.builder()
                .decoder(new GsonDecoder())
                .target(GitHub.class, "https://api.github.com");
  }

  public void callMeForEveryRequest() {
    github.contributors... // Is this thread-safe...?
  }
}
```

For the example above... I've used spring based components to highlight a singleton. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Short answer: Yes, it is thread-safe. Long answer: It can still be used in non-thread-safe ways. As long as all of the code you plug into your `Feign.builder()` is stateless, and any `Param.Expander` classes you use are stateless, you should be safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/issues/214#issuecomment-100905212) discussion seems to suggest that it *is* thread safe.  (Talks about creating a new object being inefficient)
Had a look at the source and there doesn't seem to be any state that would make it unsafe.  This is expected as it is modelled on the jersey Target.  But you should get a confirmation from the Feign devs or do your own tests and review before using it in an unsafe way.

Answer (score 1):

After a deep dive into the [feign-core](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/tree/master/core) code and a couple other feign modules (we needed additional support for things that weren't there so I had to modify some stuff -- plus, this question made me curious so I took another look), it looks like you should be safe re-using Feign clients in a multi-threaded environment as long as all of your local code (such as any custom `Encoder`, `Expander`, or `RequestInterceptor` classes, etc) has no mutable state.

The Feign internals don't store much in the way of mutable state, but some things are cached and re-used (thus may be called from multiple threads at the same time, if you are calling your Feign target's methods from multiple threads at the same time), so your plugins should be stateless.

It looks to me like all the main [Feign](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign) modules were written with immutability and statelessness in mind as a goal.

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking, but unfortunately found nothing. The only signs provides in Spring configuration. The builder is defined as bean in scope prototype, so should not be thread safe.

```
@Configuration
public class FooConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    public Feign.Builder feignBuilder() {
        return Feign.builder();
    }
}
```

reference: http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html#spring-cloud-feign-hystrix

Comment: It make sense for builder to be a prototype, don't you think so? The goal of builder is to create a new immutable object, setting up properties non-atomically. The object being built can be immutable, final and threadsafe.

Comment: The builder is definitely *not* thread-safe. But the built target is relatively thread-safe. Since it may call external plugins, it *can* be used in a non-thread-safe way, but the main Feign code appears thread-safe itself.

Answer (score 0):

In feign/core/src/main/java/feign/Client.java, there is a comment

/**
 * Submits HTTP {@link Request requests}. Implementations are expected to be thread-safe.
 */
public interface Client {

So, from the designer's point of view, it should be thread-safety.